# Downgrade SQL Express 2008 R2 SP2 (x86) to SP1

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to update vCenter from 5.0 to 5.1U1. In order to do the update, I need to downgrade the current SQL Express 2008 R2 SP2 to SP1 according to VMware compatibility matrix. Can I just uninstall the SP2 from installed updates and install SP1 afterwards? Is there anything I should be aware of beforehand? At the moment, from the update list in Control Panel, it's only got SP2 installed.

Cheers,
Jo

Comment: It's been awhile since I've installed or upgraded vCenter Server. Was SP2 part of the 5.0 install? If so, it seems counterintuitive that a vCenter Server upgrade would require a downgrade of SQL Server.

Comment: Also, why not just upgrade to vCenter Server 5.5?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm keen to set up a linked mode with a vCenter in DR so I'm trying to match the version.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just uninstall the SP2 from installed updates and install SP1 afterwards?

[Yes, that's how you would downgrade SQL Server from SP2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c30953e9-20f8-437e-b2be-1b86bf12704f/process-to-downgrade-sql-server-2008-r2-sp2-to-sp1-on-windows-2008r2?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade).  And if SP1 wasn't installed, you'd have to install it afterwards to have it.

### ***HOWEVER...***

1. Double check your compatibility matrix.  [vCenter Server 5.1 Update 1 supports SQL Server 2008 R2, SP2](https://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-vcenter-server-51u1-release-notes.html#beforeyoubegin).
2. There's no such thing as a minor ESXi or vCenter upgrade.  They're all horrible.  Given that, you should probably consider upgrading to [vSphere 5.5](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2052334).  Doubly so because there are a lot of known issues in upgrading from 5.1 to 5.5, so by jumping over 5.1, you might just avoid some of that pain.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply. I'm using sql express at the moment. It seems that SQL express 2008 R2 SP2 (x86 or x64) doesn't support vcenter 5.1U. Could you point me the right direction? cheers

Comment: @user209781 Yeah, seems you're right.  vCenter 5.5 supports SQL Server 2008 R2, SP2, though, which what I'd upgrade to.  If you're hellbent on vCenter 5.1, though, then you'll have to uninstall SP2 from your SQL server and apply SP1.  Gross, but that's what the compatibility matrix says.  (Seems to me like another argument in favor of upgrading your vCenters to 5.5, but whatever...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would love to upgrade to 5.5 but there are some issues with process at the moment. Thanks again!